# Java makes me choose which class to use instead of running both

Tags: java, animation

As the title says program makes me choose between which class I want to run, when I need both running at the same  time

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Animation extends JPanel {
    int x = 250;
    int y = 600;
    protected void moveBall() {
        x = x + 0;
        y = y - 1;
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 25, 25);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animation");
        Animation game1 = new Animation();
        frame.add(game1);
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            game1.moveBall();
            game1.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);    
        }
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Animation1 extends JPanel {
    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = 300;
    protected void moveBall() {
        x1 = x1 + 1;
        y1 = y1 + 0;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(x1, y1, 25, 25);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Animation");
        Animation1 game1 = new Animation1();
        frame.add(game1);
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            game1.moveBall();
            game1.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);    
        }
    }
}
```

I need the two lines to intersect one going left to right one going bottom to top, so I need them both running at the same time, I have no clue if the way I did this is at all correct or if there is a better way, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

first and foremost:  You currently have two entry points to your program, which is not  really what you want.

I would refactor this to use a single main(String[] args) method.